# Firebase publishers while offline

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand the consequences of an app relying on Firebase Realtime Database as its source of truth for, say, a list of items named cards.

Let's say one has a design like this

[image]

Let's say the app subscribes to cards and when the list of card changes, the app publishes it internally. In Swift terms, it may look like this:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var cards: [Card] = []

  init() {
    dataManager.cardPublisher
      .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] (cards) in
         self?.cards = cards
      })
      .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

We know that if I update the database via the Console, the app will receive the emitted value and "publish" the changes internally through the view model.

Another way for the subscriber to receive a value is for the app itself to update db.

And that is the case I am interested in: what happens if the app is "offline" and a request to update the db is successful? Would the subscriber receive a value emit a value? Note that the Firebase states that it keeps a local state of the database for precisely offline functionality and operations would be queued up so that when app goes online, the local and cloud states are synchronized.

Assume cardPublisher is a publisher is used in a Firebase db reference’s ‘observe(.value) ’, such that on a value change this publisher emits a value.

‘’’

```
    // receive event any time the path and anything under it changes. 
    cardsDbReference.observe(.value, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
        var carda: [Card] = []
        for case let childSnapshot as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            guard let value = childSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("Error: Could not retrieve cards.")
                continue
            }

            do {
                let cardData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let card = try decoder.decode(Card.self, from: cardData)
                cards.append(card)
            } catch {
                print("Decoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        self?.cardPublisher.send(cards)
    })
```

‘’’

Comment: You haven't shown any code for `dataManager` or `cardPublisher`, so it's not possible to know if it will emit a value when offline.

Comment: True. Addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand everything in your question, so I'll focus on how the database and SDK work.

- Events for local write operation file immediately when you call the API to write. This means that your `cardsDbReference.observe(.value` closure will get called for local writes that affect `cardsDbReference`, even when the client is not connected to the database.
- [Completion listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#add_a_completion_block) only fire when the data has been committed/rejected by the server. So any completion listener you may have won't fire until the client is connected to the database again.

I recommend testing this, as seeing both in action makes it clearer than an explanation typically does.

Comment: Frank, apologize for the less-than-ideal description. 

This explanation's first bullet is the answer. TY.